# Deploy Python Script On cloud

Tags: python, firebase, flask, deployment, cloud

I have a Flask project.
The front-end page is devleoped by React, and front-end send the post request to the flask app and get the data from back-end. Now I am deploy the front-end on the firebase. When front-end send the post request to the back-end, the front-end is running https, but back-end is running http. So I change it into https but there is some problems like "xhr.js:251     POST 'URL' net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" error. So I want to deploy my python backend app on cloud.
And I don't want to use Docker. How can I do it? Help me.

I trying to deploy my python app on firebase. But it need docker image.
I don't want to use it. Is there any method to solve this problem?